# Omega Layout Configuration

Tags: theming

I'm new to Drupal and Omega theme. I made a subtheme of Omega 3.x HTML 5 using Omega tools.

I need to configure zones and regions in theme settings, Thus i went Home » Administration » Appearance » Settings (on my subtheme) > Zone and region configuration.

But those zones are not configurable. and I cannot click on those. Where did i do the mistake ?

[image: snap]

Comment: what type of config you required?

Comment: In the documents i read, Those User Zone, Branding Zone are collapsible. There are settings we can set after clicking on them. But mine isn't. Is there any place to allow section config ?

Comment: I suspect you have a JS conflict.  Are you using jQuery update by any chance?  If so, disable it and see what happens.  Also check Firebug for JS errors, and report back.

Comment: Thanks for showing me correct path to find the issue. It was Javascript conflict caused by a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: It was a Javascript/jQuery conflict.

Comment: Can you expand a bit and mention what was conflicting with the Omega admin pages?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go in with firebug and check first that those collapsible blocks contain the HTML form content you expect to be there and that it is simply hidden by CSS rule(s). Then if that is true then edit the CSS for those collapsible blocks to make them able to dismay content.
If there is no form content there then possibly could be a permissions issue at a guess.